# Lock in text in Python editor? And lock text in Python within boundaries?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I had written some Lorum Ipsum filler words in my coding to test out the words, but I have got two distinct issues with words not going to another neat line. I am having problems with both the code editor neatness and the program itself. Below I will write down all the problems I am currently having in both the editor and the program.

**Editor problem:** I am not sure how to make my editor lock these words into the boundaries of my editor and not go into some extremely long line that I cannot scroll leftwards to reach back to my original code. I haven't found anything on the editor that pushes words back to the left of the editor. I am using IDLE editor, and I cannot yet find a function that pushes words back to the left, yet I could find it well using Notepad++ when I work on HTML. And I do not know how to use Notepad++ to code Python, and would rather continue using IDLE editor.

**Program GUI problem**: The Lorum Ipsum words aren't locking together in that neat 960px-wide program in the Tkinter GUI I made. I don't understand how to fix it. When I tried the ".grid" function instead of the ".pack" function, it would give an error if I try to also put a drawing below it. When I tried the ".pack" function, it would not error, but the words aren't locking within the boundaries of the program as it would be expected, and instead the words are just centered in one line.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("960x600")

label_toptitle = tk.Label(root,
                      text="Program Name",
                      font=(None, 40),
)
label_toptitle.pack(side="top", fill="x")

label_desc = Label(root,
               text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus. Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus tincidunt. Duis leo. Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc,",
               bd=1,
               #relief="solid",
               font=(None, 20),
               padx=20,
               pady=10)
label_desc.pack(side="top", fill="x")
##label_desc.grid(row=0,
##                #sticky=E
##                )

canvas = Canvas(width=960, height=300, bg='white')
canvas.pack(expand=YES, fill=BOTH)

canvas.create_rectangle(278, 20, 664, 114, width=5, fill='pink')
canvas.create_rectangle(70, 140, 888, 284, width=5, fill='pink')
canvas.create_rectangle(70, 318, 888, 408, width=5, fill='pink')
canvas.create_rectangle(257, 468, 349, 557, width=5, fill='pink')
canvas.create_rectangle(430, 468, 520, 557, width=5, fill='pink')
canvas.create_rectangle(597, 468, 689, 557, width=5, fill='pink')

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: _"I haven't found anything on the editor that pushes words back to the left of the editor."_ - are you asking how to get the text to `wrap` automatically, or are you asking how to force a new line?

Comment: Please limit a question to a single issue instead of combining several questions into one.

Comment: I am both trying to get my editor to align the text to push to the side and also trying to get the words in my GUI program to fit within the boundaries of my program.

Comment: By the way, how do I add screenshots? I'd like to add a screenshot to show what exactly I mean by each of the two problems.

Comment: Also, I searched the definition of "wrap". Does the definition "cause (a word or unit of text) to be carried over to a new line automatically as the margin is reached, or to fit around embedded features such as pictures" fit the description you are referring to? That is exactly what I am referring to.